# Scala line splitting issue

Tags: scala

```
val filePath = "src/main/resources/millionsong.txt"
val rdd = sc.textFile(filePath)
val recordsRdd = rdd.map(line => line.split(","))
recordsRdd.foreach(println)
```

I am just starting with Scala. I am not understanding why output is ?
...
[Ljava.lang.String;@116c19d8
...

One line of Rdd is:
2001.0,0.884123733793,0.610454259079,0.600498416968,0.474669212493,0.247232680947,0.357306088914,0.344136412234,0.339641227335,0.600858840135,0.425704689024,0.60491501652,0.419193351817

I am thinking that output should be array of numbers?

Comment: that's a typical `toString` of an array. You probably need to look inside to find the content.

Comment: It see youve asked a python question, so why not use PySpark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct code that would print the values would be :

```
val filePath = "src/main/resources/millionsong.txt"
val rdd = sc.textFile(filePath)
val recordsRdd = rdd.flatMap(line => line.split(","))
recordsRdd.foreach(println)
```

The problem is that what you are doing is you are mapping on the `RDD` and then splitting the string hence resulting into `Array[String]` and you are  not flattening it earlier, Hence resultant RDD would be of type: `RDD[Array[String]]`. Hence When you try to print using `recordsRdd.foreach(println)` what it was doing is that it tries to print the Array object and hence displaying weird values.

If you want to print the values per array then this would work like this:

```
val filePath = "src/main/resources/millionsong.txt"
val rdd = sc.textFile(filePath)
val recordsRdd = rdd.map(line => line.split(","))
recordsRdd.foreach(_.foreach(println))
```

Answer (score 1):

`String.split` returns `Array[String]`, so you are trying to print array. Scala array is plain java array, that's why it has such unreadable `toString`. Depending on what you want to achieve, you should use either `record.Rdd.foreach(_.foreach(println))` or `val recordsRdd = rdd.flatMap(line => line.split(","))`. Not sure if a type of 'Rdd' (Spark RDD?) is compatible with scala collections. If it's not, then `flatMap` will not work.

Answer (score -4):

Use flatMap instead map on rdd.